# Using a JSON list array with Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, image

Im in the middle of a project and am a little bit stuck. I have an image viewer that takes an array of URL's and puts out a gallery of pictures. All that works great. What I am struggling with is instead of having it use pre determined links, have it use the links from  my database. When I call the database I get a result something like this "name":" "http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-jZgveEqb6pg/T3R4kXScycI/AAAAAAAAAE0/xQ7CvpfXDzc/s1024/sample_image_01.jpg" 
Im not sure how to be able to use this result and put it into my image viewer. Right now all the URLs are in an array and my query is an array list. This is another thing that is confusing me

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                list.add(jArray.get(i).toString()); 
        }
```

Thats my query call and how I get my array list. Any pointers or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: you will need to download image first and then put it in ImageView src

Comment: I got that I am using googles image caching example from the development website. I have all the images downloading fine from a array of URLs but I am trying to change from that array to an array list from my database

Comment: So you want to convert an ArrayList<String> to a JSONArray?

Comment: No I have a JsonArray and I convert it to an Array List but I need help with how to use it. I am confused on how to get android to understand that what it is getting is a url.

Comment: I am still confused. Do you want to convert your ArrayList to an array (not JSONArray) to pass it to your image viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it that you want? Iterate the list?

```
for (String url : list) {
    // Do something with url
}
```

Comment: I have that much what I want to know is how to use that array list. How do I get the information out of the array list so it is useable

Comment: This should get me started on the right track thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to use pre-defined data (from database) to populate your picture gallery.
First you have to get cursor out from database and looping through all rows and add to arraylist

```
//Get db crusor
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM table", null);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// looping through all rows and adding to Arraylist
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        //get string from database cursor and add it to arraylist
        list.add(cursor.getString(1));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

[This link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) can help you to understand using database in android

Comment: Im trying to use MySql not SquLite any recommendations on that front?

Comment: So you want to use data from MySQL in android. Try this one
 http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/